# : Error CS1729: 'SQLiteConnection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments (CS1729)

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.android

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this error message

Error CS1729: 'SQLiteConnection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments (CS1729)

this is the files where it is happening

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SQLite;
using Android.Util;

using SQLite.Net;

namespace CPDEP1
{
    public class DataBase
    {
        string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        public bool createDataBase()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")));
                {
                    connection.CreateTable<Person>();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch(SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool insertIntoTablePerson(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")))
                {
                    connection.Insert(person);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch(SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public List<Person> selectTablePerson()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")))
                {
                    return connection.Table<Person>().ToList();

                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public bool updateTablePerson(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")))
                {
                    connection.Query<Person>("UPDATE Person set Nom=?,Prenom=?,Telephone=?,Addresse=?,Courriel=?,Cin=? Where Id=?,",person.Nom,person.Prennom,person.Telephone,person.Addresse,person.Courriel,person.Cin,person.Id);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool deleteTablePerson(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")))
                {
                    connection.Delete(person);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool selectQueryTablePerson(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")))
                {
                    connection.Query<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person Where Id=?", Id);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Actually I am using Xamarin Studio and i have only one project and solution

Comment: I think your database connection string should start with `"DataSource="`

Comment: Are you sure you have the right library, this one, https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net has `SQLiteConnection` with one constructor as your code does and has the namespace `using namespace SQLite`, whereas `using namespace SQLite.Net` in addition looks like this library https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL, and requires an additional parameter to the `SQLiteConnection` (the platform instance).

Comment: You were right sir!! Iwas using the wrong library I uninstall the one I was using and replace it with the correct one and everything work just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was following the instruction here: https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/09/10/adding-a-sqlite-database-to-xamarin-forms/ and got the same error.

Then I referred to Microsoft instruction here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx) and noticed there are 2 very similar thing both written by Frank Krueger. Please check the image below, download the one that is highlighted in GREEN, not the RED one.

[image]

Comment: green and red squares help me notice my mistake in less than a sec ! Thx !